# How do I receive user input for a dungeon crawler?

Tags: input, pseudocode

So, I am planning on **designing** a dungeon crawler (like Nethack), and I was wondering how I could get the user's input for moving the player. I originally planned to get a character input (W,S,A, or D) and then when the user presses enter, the movement takes place.

However, now I'd like to implement this without the mandatory enter press, so that merely pressing W would move the player forward by one space. I don't really need syntactically correct code, just pseudo-code of a concept would suffice.

Comment: Capturing a `KEYDOWN` event won't work?

Comment: Would they work if creating a Java or C++ console file? I wasn't sure

Comment: It depends on how you're capturing the input, but unless you're waiting for input that should work.

Comment: I am waiting, in the sense that the input for movement should work like in any FPS or RPG or whatever

Comment: Ok.  If you are using a prompt, an enter keypress is required.  If you are just running your game loop you can use system events and simply capture those without a prompt.  That's what most games do.

Comment: Right, that'll probably work. Thanks!